# Facebook Javascript SDK Not Initializing

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to incorporate Facebook sharing into the website I'm building.  I'm following FB's guide for including their Javascript SDK (and copy/pasting their code inside a script tag directly following the body tag) but for some reason it isn't working.  In the following code "running" is successfully printed but the "Initialized" never prints and the shareFacebook function is never successfully initialized.  Does anyone know why this is?

```
console.log("Running init script");
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '444853392519445',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

  function shareFacebook() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
    }, function (response) {
    });

    console.log("Inside shareFacebook");
  }

  console.log("Initialized");
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

Comment: You are calling the page you have put this in via http/https, and not just via the local file system, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that I had the same Problem with Facebook SDK. Can you test with

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
```

and remove also `version    : 'v2.8'`.

Comment: `all.js` is the old version of the SDK, and it doesn’t support event logging. `sdk.js` is what should be used.